# how to use version control in project with different languages?

Tags: svn, version-control

When we are developing web applications frequently we have a lot of code in many languages (HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, AS3, etc). 
Is better to have a different repository for each language or just one global repository for all the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version control system are usually split by *projects*, not by *source language*

If you are building a, say, web application, it is a normal thing (and it's perfectly fine) to have files with different programming languages in it (HTML, CSS, PHP, JS, etc).

To answer your question:

No it is not a good idea to have a different repository for each *source language*.

Just use one repository for all the applications. In fact, most companies will probably have one repository for all the projects in the company.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to split the repository *by source language*.  Just use one common trunk -- and organize your code as you would in a tar archive.  In other words, let the logic of your project determine how you archive it.

SVN can deal with many different file types, and sources are after all ASCII text in almost all cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you, really. I'd suggest that the repository represent the application. It's much more logical this way (app->repository, module-> root dir) than separating based on languages.